# Application-level locking and hibernate optimistic locking

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, hibernate

I'm using hibernate optimistic locking with MariaDB like

```
@Version
@Column(columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP(3) DEFAULT '2016-01-01'")
private Timestamp timestamp;
```

Recently, I've got a `StaleStateException`, and as a quick hack, I tried to fight it via locking in the application. This leads to the following sequence (the second column is a thread number; each thread has its own connection):

```
A 1 createSession
B 2 createSession
C 1 read some irrelevant entity
D 2 read some irrelevant entity
E 1 try to obtain lock
F 2 try to obtain lock
G 1 LOCK GRANTED
H 1 READ THE ENTITY, timestamp=2016-09-28 14:52:32.076
I 1 do some other stuff
J 1 WRITE THE ENTITY, new timestamp=2016-09-28 14:52:32.076
K 1 COMMIT
L 1 release lock
M 2 LOCK GRANTED
N 1 READ THE ENTITY, timestamp=2016-09-28 14:52:32.076
O 2 do some other stuff
P 2 WRITE THE ENTITY, StaleStateException
```

The problem is obviously in line N where the second thread sees the old timestamp. I didn't specify the isolation level anywhere, the default for Mysql should be [REPEATABLE READ](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html), but AFAIK no level except 
even SNAPSHOT or SERIALIZABLE should make the second thread see the old value, should it?

*I can see that application level locking is a bad idea, I'm just trying to understand what's going on, before I switch to retrying or DB locking.*

**A possible reason is me using JodaTime Instant for versioning**,
[which is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44379299/581205).

Comment: and what happens if you do not "read some irrelevant entity"?

Comment: @JohnDonn I don't know and I can't find it easily out as it's an extract from a real code where it can't be easily removed. Making an SSCCE would surely help, but it's rather complicated. +++ I guess, the new timestamp would be read, as `createSession` is lazy. But that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

What you haven't stated is where the Transactions start and end.

If each session starts a transaction at steps A & B, then yes indeed, Serializable would mean that session 2 would only ever see the old timestamp unitl it commits and starts a new transaction.

If session 2 used Read Committed, it would see the new value after session 1 commits.

In this example JPA is doing exactly what you are asking, and using the Version field to avoid a buried update.  If you don't care, and want to do the update anyway, don't use Version...?