# Using JodaTime Instant for versioning with Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Using `java.time.Instant` with Hibernate works (I'm using `hibernate-java8`, more  solutions are given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26455446/581205)). Using it as `@Version` is a problem.

I'm using Hibernate 5.1.7.Final with (a mix of legacy and JPA) annotations. My entities are versioned using

```
@javax.persistence.Version
@javax.persistence.Column(
    columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP(3) DEFAULT '2016-01-01'")
private Instant mytimestamp;
```

which MySQL interprets as

```
`mytimestamp` timestamp(3) NOT NULL
    DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)
    ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)
```

This is crazy enough, but not my point.

I wanted to know how Hibernate assigns `mytimestamp`, if I can change the way and if I can retrieve the value. It looks like all three answers are "NO".

- Hibernate does not assign `mytimestamp`; it gets assigned `ON UPDATE` by MySQL. This won't work with a DB not supporting this hack. I wonder if this is intentional or a if it just works by accident.
- So I added `@org.hibernate.annotations.Source(SourceType.VM)` only to find out that the version generation uses `TimestampType.seed(SessionImplementor session)` returning new `java.sql.Timestamp`, which can't be assigned to a field of type `Instant`. With `SourceType.DB`, I get `DbTimestampType`, which is a subclass of `TimestampType` resulting in the same exception.
- I can't see how I could retrieve the timestamp without an additional query.

So my questions:

- Can I make Hibernate assign `Instant mytimestamp`?
- Or can I make it call my code, so I can assign it myself?

Comment: How do you mean MySQL interprets? Are you generating the schema from the entities? Do you really want to have the update trigger? Usually, if you are using application level optimistic locking, the framework (Hibernate) assigns the value for the version attribute and not the DB with a trigger.

Comment: @galovics I let Hibernate to create the schema. MySQL does the funny thing itself, where you create a TIMESTAMP column.I don't like it and I'd prefer Hibernate to do it, but this is how it went. And it looks like Hibernate can't do it with `Instant`s as it expects `java.sql.Timestamp`s.

Comment: JPA 2.1 is part of the EE7 spec, and as such it does not support the Java 8 time classes. A workaround could be to use a Date, and the convert from/to `Instant` inside your getter/setter.

Comment: Sorry, I have to comment to: "This won't work with a DB not supporting this hack. I wonder if this is intentional or a if it just works by accident." I suppose, you told hibenate, that you are working with mysql. So they exploit this quite nifty feature. The idea is not to let you see how the individual capabilities of a database used, so that you can work as dbms-agnostic as possible. Why do you need Instant here? Do you want to manipulate the inserted or returned timestamp for tests?

Comment: Can you also show all the annotations available on the `mytimestamp ` field and on the entity itself? `columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP(3) DEFAULT '2016-01-01'"` should not generate `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)` at least if there are no other special configs for that.

Comment: @Andreas Concerning dbms-agnostic, I'd agree with you if there wasn't the problem with `@org.hibernate.annotations.Source` not working at all. concerning `Instant`, what else? It's an instant of time and the alternatives are `long` and `java.sql.Timestamp`. The former is semantically wrong and the latter is mutable. Both are usable *workarounds*, but nothing more.

Comment: @Babl I gave all annotations, that all. This auto-adding of `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is an old MySQL "feature" - it adds it by itself to the first `TIMESTAMP` column. It's damn crazy and AFAIK off by default in the lastest version.